# How can I run the equivalent “curl” command that performs similarly to this “wget” command?

Tags: wget, curl

I have a [`wget`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) command:

```
wget -r --no-parent -nH -nd -q --show-progress --progress=bar:force ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/swdi/database-csv/v2/
```

But it only works in newer versions of `wget`. Unfortunately I have an older version of `wget` (GNU Wget 1.15 built on darwin14.3.0) and can’t upgrade it. Specifically it’s the `wget` `--show-progress` option that isn’t recognized.

I am wondering if there is an equivalent command for [`curl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)? The version of `curl` on my system is 7.37.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0).

Comment: I wish I could. I think it was installed with brew, but it's not my computer so I can't just update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it only works in newer versions of `wget`. Unfortunately I have an
>   older version of `wget` (GNU Wget 1.15 built on darwin14.3.0) and
>   can’t upgrade it. Specifically it’s the `wget` `--show-progress`
>   option that isn’t recognized.

Based on what I know about how `curl` works and how `wget` works, they might superficially seem the same but there is no equivalent of `wget` recursive functionality in `curl`. To do something like that in `curl` requires some fancy Bash scripting to wrap around the `curl` command.

So when you say you can’t upgrade `wget`, what exactly do you mean? Since `wget` is a GNU tool, it’s not installed with Darwin (which is BSD-based) and is often compiled from source. In fact the version details you have provided is clearly compiled from source in some way since the version is “GNU Wget 1.15 built on darwin14.3.0.” So if that version of `wget` was installed by something like [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), there is hope since if Homebrew is on your system then you should have Xcode—and related command line tools/compilers—installed on your system as well.

Now knowing that, you should be able to compile an updated version of `wget`—such as 1.16.3—from source; bypassing the Homebrew installed version and just having it executable from your home directory. You don’t have `root`/`sudo` access to do this; here’s how you can do it.

#### Compiling `wget` from source.

First grab a compressed archive from an official `wget` source site:

```
curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.16.3.tar.gz
```

Next, decompress the archive like this:

```
tar -xzf wget-1.*.tar.gz
```

Now go into the decompressed directory:

```
cd wget-1.*
```

Run this `configure` command:

```
./configure --with-ssl=openssl
```

If somehow that `configure` command fails, you might need to add a `--with-libssl-prefix`value like this:

```
./configure --with-ssl=openssl --with-libssl-prefix=/usr/lib
```

Once the `configure` process completes, run `make`:

```
make
```

If that runs cleanly a newly compiled version of the `wget` 1.16.3 binary is ready for you to use.

#### Running the freshly compiled version of `wget` from your home directory.

Now at this point, most instructions would say you should run `sudo make install` to get `wget` fully installed on the system. But if you don’t have `root`/`sudo` privileges—or you don’t want to upgrade the `wget` version that is installed system-wide—you can still run the `wget` binary you just compiled like this. First, let’s back out of your `wget` source directory like this:

```
cd ~/
```

Now just run the `wget` 1.16.3 binary you just compiled explicitly like this to confirm it’s working:

```
~/wget-1.16.3/src/wget --version
```

The output should be something like this:

```
GNU Wget 1.16.3 built on darwin13.4.0.

+digest +https +ipv6 -iri +large-file -nls +ntlm +opie -psl +ssl/openssl 

Wgetrc: 
    /usr/local/etc/wgetrc (system)
Compile: 
    gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC="/usr/local/etc/wgetrc" 
    -DLOCALEDIR="/usr/local/share/locale" -I. -I../lib -I../lib 
    -DNDEBUG 
Link: 
    gcc -DNDEBUG -liconv -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lz ftp-opie.o openssl.o 
    http-ntlm.o ../lib/libgnu.a 

Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Originally written by Hrvoje Niksic <hniksic@xemacs.org>.
Please send bug reports and questions to <bug-wget@gnu.org>.
```

Which means you are now in business!

#### Running your `wget` command from your home directory.

So you can now run the `wget` command posted in your question like this:

```
~/wget-1.16.3/src/wget -r --no-parent -nH -nd -q --show-progress --progress=bar:force ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/swdi/database-csv/v2/
```

And a small tweak—but one worth noting—is that many `wget` options have full names and shortened acronyms. So `--no-parent` can be shortened to `-np` to make the command look like this:

```
~/wget-1.16.3/src/wget -r -np -nH -nd -q --show-progress --progress=bar:force ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/swdi/database-csv/v2/
```

#### Post-usage cleanup.

And if you want to get rid of the `wget` 1.16.3 stuff you just compiled—since you say the computer you are working on is not yours—then just delete the `wget` source files you just worked with like this:

```
rm wget-1.16.3.tar.gz
rm -rf wget-1.16.3
```